# perl: unable to open a file for reading sometimes

Tags: perl

If a file in a directory matches some nomenclature, then it is to be processed.

I have problem with the following piece of code:

```
if ($fichier =~ /0284\-\d{4}-\w{6}\.0284\.UPDREQ\.\d{4}\.\d{10}/)
{
 my $msg = "Processing file is : $fichier \n";
 Trace($EXP, __FILE__, __LINE__, "$msg");
}
if(!open (FILE, "< $fichier"))
{
 my $cmd = "mv $REP_FLOTS/$fichier $REP_UPDREQ_ARCH/err_$fichier";
 system("$cmd");
}
$lines++ while (<FILE>);
close FILE;
```

It is able to open and read the content sometimes and it fails in other times.
What am I missing in this code? Because it is working fine sometimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you ask system itself about what's going wrong? Variable `$!` holds last error for previous system call, so if open failed, just print it:

```
if(!open (FILE, "< $fichier"))
{
 warn "unable to open '$fichier' for reading: $!\n";
 my $cmd = "mv $REP_FLOTS/$fichier $REP_UPDREQ_ARCH/err_$fichier";
 system("$cmd");
}
```

Comment: Using FILE as file-handler might have caused the problem.
when I changed it, I didnt find any issue.